# Why I'm getting undefined instead of edge using tanstack's queryClient.getQueriesData()?

Tags: tanstack

I'm using tanstack' query.

Using the code below I'm getting always `undefined` as the `initialData` value, why? I expect to get `edge` instead.

Obviously in the cache are present the `edges` for `playerKeys.lists()` (from the list view).

```
//... player_id comes from here

const playerStore = createQuery({
  queryKey: playerKeys.byId(player_id),
  queryFn: playerById(player_id),
  initialData: () => {
    // I'm using getQueriesData not getQueryData here
    const lists = queryClient.getQueriesData<playerListConnection>(
      playerKeys.lists()
    );

    return lists.find((query) => {
      return query[1]?.edges.find((edge) => {
        return edge.id === player_id;
      });
    });
  },
});
```